# How to fix web connection failed to load data from my database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

Im trying to create a simple database load connection through web page but it always give me an error: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

This is my web.config, using MySQL, MySQL server 2005

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MySQLConnection" connectionString="database=peronrecords;server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And this is my vb code using gridview:

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MySQLConnection").ToString())
        ' Create a DataSet object. 
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, name FROM student", conn)
        da.Fill(dt)

        ' Open the connection 
        conn.Open()

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connecting to MySql then you need to use the appropriate classes.
The SqlConnection and SqlDataAdapter are the classes required to connect to Microsoft Sql Server, for MySql you need the `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlDataAdapter`.

These classes could be found if you download and install the [MySql NET Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), then [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to `MySql.Data.dll` and add an [Imports statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx) for `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` to the top of your code file.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MySQLConnection").ToString())
        ' Create a DataSet object'
        Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, name FROM student", conn)
        da.Fill(dt)

        ' Not needed. The DataAdapter opens the connection by itself if it is not opened
        ' conn.Open()

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to expand on that a bit, the types used in the original code are members of the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace, which is for SQL Server specifically.  You can download and install Connector/NET from MySQL and then you'll have access to the corresponding members of the `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` namespace, which is specifically for MySQL.

Comment: @jmcilhinney was just typing about it

Comment: But when i am using local application/stand alone application(not a web page) it is working by using ODBC.

Comment: ODBC uses different drivers and they are probably preinstalled. However, you should run with the MySql connector for better performance and features

Comment: I already installed mysql-connector-net-6.9.5 but I connot find or import data.mysqlclien. It only finds sqlclient.

Comment: You should find it in C:\program files\MySql, Right click on References folder in your project, then Browse and go to the installation directory of MySql\MySql Net Connector XXXXX

Comment: Done with codes and reference mysql and I run again my web page but another MySQL Exceptio error: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.